# how to post data without passing it to model .Net Core

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I have this in my view

```
<form class="d-inline-block" asp-controller="">
                      <div class="form-group mb-2 d-inline-block">
                          <input type="text" readonly class="form-control-plaintext border-bottom " placeholder="Task Number">
                      </div>
                      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-2">Assign</button>
                  </form>
```

this is the method that i have in my controller called `ManageController`

```
public IActionResult AssignTask(string tasknumber,string userid,string username)
    {
        SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection(".....");
        sqlcon.Open();
        SqlCommand sqlcom = new SqlCommand("...", sqlcon);
        sqlcom.ExecuteNonQuery();
        sqlcon.Close();
        return RedirectToAction("Members", new { Username = username });
    }
```

how can i pass all those parameters to the controller when the user hits submit without using `asp-for` for the input.

Comment: How about this code `<input type="hidden" name="tasknumber" value="aa"/>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following code:

```
<form class="d-inline-block" asp-controller="Manage" asp-action="AssignTask">
<div class="form-group mb-2 d-inline-block">
    <input type="hidden" name="tasknumber" value="yourvalue"/>
    //...
    <input type="text" readonly class="form-control-plaintext border-bottom " placeholder="Task Number">
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-2">Assign</button>
</form>
```

Method:

```
 [HttpPost]
 public IActionResult AssignTask(string tasknumber,string userid,string username)
    {
     //...
    }
```

In the same way, in your input box, you only need to give it a `name` that is the same as the method`parameter name` to transfer to the method.